# Перетаскивание объектов мышкой

Tags: java, javafx

доброго времени суток. Подскажите что делаю не правильно. Пытаюсь написать код, позволяющий перетаскивать объекты мышкой. Объекты после перемещения и вращения определяются на своих старых местах.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;


public class Main extends Application {
Point2D offset;
Node selected;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(40, 20, 50, 100);
    rect.setRotate(90);
    Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(450, 450, 50, 25);
    ellipse.setRotate(45);
    Circle circle = new Circle(250, 250, 50);
    root.getChildren().addAll(rect, ellipse, circle);

    root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            offset = new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY());
            e.consume();
        }
    });

    root.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {   
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            for(Node node: root.getChildren()){
                if(node.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())){
                    selected = node;
                    root.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
                    break;
                }else{
                    selected = null;
                    root.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
                }
            }
            e.consume();
        }
    });

    root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            if(selected != null){
                selected.setTranslateX(e.getX() - offset.getX());
                selected.setTranslateY(e.getY() - offset.getY());
            }
            e.consume();
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: А как программа должна себя вести?